# Using dynamically generated entity name in ORM Coldfusion

Tags: orm, coldfusion

I'm trying to load a persistent ORM Entity by retrieving its name from the database but it keeps giving me an error. The error states no CFC with the name exists but it displays the name of the CF clearly in the error and it is correct. Perhaps this is something that is not possible?

Here's the sample code (some variables are obviously dynamically generated but not part of the sample below)

```
<cfset friendlyColumn = entityLoad("importFriendlyNames",{friendly_name=#matchingStruct[columns]#})>

<cfloop array="#friendlyColumn#" index="fl">

    <!--- find the entity from the value in the database -- this fails --->
    <cfset newEntity = entityNew("#fl.getforeign_key_type()#")>
    
    
    <cfset newEntity.setName("#cd[columns][currentrow]#")>
    <cfset entitySave(newEntity)>

</cfloop>
```

Is the syntax incorrect or is this not possible?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think all the potential entities are loaded `onApplicationStart()`

This suggests that you are creating and destroying DB tables very quickly. Is that your intent?

Comment: I am not creating or destroying DB Tables, I am initiating an instance of a persistent entity in order to write to the DB. However, I am looping over an array so the entity is initiated every loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. There was blank space when retrieving the name. When I used

`<cfset newEntity = entityNew("#trim(fl.getforeign_key_type())#")>`

it worked.

Thanks